# Tail Recursive Function is not being optimised by g++

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, tail-recursion

I have this simple DFS Code for the the Number of Islands problem but I even though is a tail recursive function when I use G++ -O2, I still get a Segmentation Fault.

```
void findneighbors(int i, int j,  int row, int column, vector<vector<char>>& binaryMatrix){
      binaryMatrix[i][j]='0';
      if((i+1)<row && binaryMatrix[i+1][j] == '1'){

        findneighbors(i+1,j, row,column, binaryMatrix);
      }

      if((i-1)>=0 && binaryMatrix[i-1][j] == '1'){
        findneighbors(i-1,j, row,column, binaryMatrix);
      }

      if((j+1)<column && binaryMatrix[i][j+1] == '1'){
        findneighbors(i,j+1, row,column, binaryMatrix);
      }

      if((j-1)>=0 && binaryMatrix[i][j-1] == '1'){
        findneighbors(i,j-1, row,column, binaryMatrix);
      }
}

int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& binaryMatrix) {
      int count = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i<binaryMatrix.size(); i++){
        for(int j =0; j<binaryMatrix[0].size(); j++){
          if(binaryMatrix[i][j]=='1'){
            findneighbors(i,j,binaryMatrix.size(),binaryMatrix[0].size(),binaryMatrix);
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
    return count;        
}
```

Comment: Interesting problem!  What have you done to figure out what goes wrong?  Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code?  Have you inserted diagnostic output statements to see what is happening?

Comment: Tail recursion could possibly eliminate only the fourth of these four recursive calls. You have three more in there that will eat up your stack faster than I can drink a cup of coffee.

Comment: I don't know if it changed with C++17 or will change with C++20, but tail-call optimization isn't so far a required part of C++, compilers aren't required to do it.

Comment: That's not tail recursion, since you perform multiple recursive calls.

Comment: How big is your matrix? Stack overflow is a possibility, I don't see any other errors.

Comment: Colud you also add the main function to get a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: The first three recursive calls of that function are not tail recursive, since they are followed by other statements (`if` statements and potentially other recursive calls).   You therefore can't expect tail recursion optimisation to be applied to all four calls  (you may get lucky, if the compiler is somehow able to transform the function into a simple tail-recursive function, but you can't rely on that).

Comment: you will have terminal recursion replacing `if .. if .. if .. if ..` by `if .. else if .. else if .. else if ..`. If you cannot do these `else if` because the cases are not exclusive that means only the last call is terminal

Comment: As you already pass vector, you don't need extra size `column`/`row` as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For tail recursion optimization to happen, the last statement should be the recursive call. See this [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-recursion/):

```
// An example of tail recursive function 
void print(int n) 
{ 
    if (n < 0)  return; 
    cout << " " << n; 

    // The last executed statement is recursive call 
    print(n-1); 
}
```

Example taken from geeksforgeeks, see the link above.

Since the main function is missing, I don't know if the binary matrix is initialized correctly and all row vectors have the same length. If the row vectors don't have the same length, `for(int j =0; j<binaryMatrix[0].size(); j++)` will allow you to access an invalid `j` index, since you always check the length of the first row of your matrix.